# Objective-C: i can't configure and use a NSPersistentStoreCoordinator

Tags: objective-c, nspersistentstore

By melting something I read on this forum and some other stuff I found in Apple's documentation, I've tried to get to a functioning NSManagedObjectContext. so, I wrote the following code:

```
    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSBundle mainBundle]]];

        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *basePath = ([paths count]>0 ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil);
        NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[basePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"meetSigns.sqlite"]];

        NSError *persistentError;

        if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:nil error:&persistentError]) {
            NSLog([persistentError description]);
        }

        NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:persistentStoreCoordinator];
```

I must precise that, at the beginning, my app had not data model, so I added it manually and now I have a .xcdatamodeld file. I used the interface to populate the model with my entities and relationships.
Anyway, I can't find a .sqlite file, even if it is required in the snippet I posted.
Maybe, as a consequence, I get the following error:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 512.)" UserInfo=0x74d6dd0 {reason=Failed to create file; code = 2}
```

How can I create this .sqlite file? can I generate it automatically from data model? I tried to use both the name of the project and the one of data model, in both cases adding .sqlite extension, but I got same error.

Beacuse of this error, I get the following, too:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores.  It cannot perform a save operation.'
```

Coud you tell me where I'm mistaking? can you tell me how to solve the problem of mixing .sqlite file?

thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `NSDocumentationDirectory` in your call to `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`, but it should be `NSDocumentDirectory`.

Comment: it seems to work, thanks  
can i ask you one more question? probably, i should create context once for ever. i saw some people creating it in app's delegate class and pass it through the root controller to other controller. how could i do it, using the code i reported above? my app is composed of a part controlled by a root controller; then, at the end of the chain of controllers, user is driven to a new controller not belonging to the chain. from that moment, isolated controllers are loaded from storyboard when needed. how to pass the context from a controller to another in this case? thanks

Comment: Yes, create once usually. I'd look at using a singleton to act as your data controller.

Comment: so, is it sufficient to copy-paste the code above somewhere inside app delegate? in which function?  
singletons is something i found many times on web, maybe time to learn it is arrived

Comment: The app delegate shouldn't be used for this - it should only be used for application level things. Owning the data model is not part of that so a special controller should be created

Comment: so, creating once in the first view controller, when app goes to first controller or an user commits registrations, is a good idea?

Comment: The singleton instance would be created the first time it's requested. It doesn't matter which controller it is that makes the request.